# Alarm Service not triggering again on specific time in OREO and older

Tags: android, push-notification, alarmmanager

I am working on an android application in which I am triggering Local push notification with Alarm service. First time (6:00 am) it is working fine even if I am removing an application from the stack, but I change my system clock again on (6:00 am), it is not triggering again. My code is given below, where I am making notifications as per API level as well.

```
// Activity where I am calling AlarmService

    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

        final static int RQS_1 = 4;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 6);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,00);
            calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

           // API LEVEL OREO or greater
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O){

            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class); //ALARM IS SET
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
            }else{
          // API LEVEL Lower than OREO
           AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

            Intent notificationIntent = new     Intent("android.media.action.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION");
            notificationIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");

            PendingIntent broadcast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,100,notificationIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
           if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),broadcast);
        } else {
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),broadcast);
        }
    }
    }
```

Alarm Receiver

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationActivity.class);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);
        localPushNotifications26GreaterAPI(context);
    }

    public void localPushNotifications26GreaterAPI(Context context){


        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

// The id of the channel.
            String id = "my_channel_01";
            CharSequence name = "iam.peace";
            String description = "Description";

            NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(id, name,importance);
            mChannel.setDescription(description);
            mChannel.enableLights(true);
            mChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            mChannel.enableVibration(true);
            mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
            mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            int notifyID = 1;
            String CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_01";
            Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(context,CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setContentTitle("OREO LEVEL NOTIFICATION")
                    .setContentText("You've received new messages.")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                    .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID)
                    .build();
            mNotificationManager.notify(notifyID, notification);
        } else{
            localPushNotifications26LowerAPI(context);
        }


    }


    public void localPushNotifications26LowerAPI(Context context){

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder b = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

        b.setAutoCancel(true)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setTicker("I am Peace")
                .setContentTitle("OREO Below LEVEL NOTIFICATION")
                .setContentText("Oreo below level push notifications.")
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS| Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setContentInfo("Info");


        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(1, b.build());
    }



}
```

Manifest file where I am registering Receiver:

```
<receiver android:name="helper.AlarmReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.media.action.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are using [setExtact](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExact(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) method which makes one-time alarm. You can either use [setRepeating](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) to make repeating alarm (but since API 19 it's no longer exact):

```
 alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis() ,60 * 60 * 24 * 1000, broadcast);
```

or create new one-time alarm in your AlarmReceiver in onReceiveMethod

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationActivity.class);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);
    localPushNotifications26GreaterAPI(context);
    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),broadcast);

}
```

Comment: thanks for your message here. I need to ask one thing, what is one-time alarm? Basically i need alarm even if my app is in background or I removed application from stack. I need this kind of alarm.

Comment: It's an alarm that will trigger only once, if you want receive broadcast in your  AlarmReceiver you need to schedule another alarm

Comment: Alarms works always, even if your app is killed. But there 4 different types (ELAPSED_REALTIME, ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, RTC, RTC_WAKEUP), and you are already using correct one (RTC_WAKEUP) for your needs. If you want to know more, check this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html).

Answer (score 0):

From Android Oreo, it is better if you go with JobScheduler, please refer google's official document,
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html